# Why isn't the Ocean modifier wave movement showing in the rendered animation?

Tags: ocean-simulation

I've created a short animation with a camera flying over an ocean.  The ocean is created by the ocean modifier.  When I scrub through the timeline the waves are moving (whether viewed through the active camera or through the 3D viewport) but when I render the animation, the ocean is static.  What am I doing wrong?  Using Blender 2.8 30th May 2019 build.

Here are the modifier settings for frame 1 and frame 650:

[image]

Comment: Is the modifier enable for rendering (camera icon)?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, it is.  I tried it on both settings.  It still didn't work.  Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: I started the blend file from scratch and now it's working.  I have no idea what is different.  Anyway, now solved.  Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the vey same issue.
I didn't realise I had to bake the animation first. Once baked I could render out individual frames within the animation cycle.
Hope this helps